# Firebase Database Delete Security Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am currently creating Firebase security rules to prevent a user from setting a node to null and deleting all the data in that node.

This is my schema

```
{
  "folder" : {
    "item1" : {
      "dataset1" : {
        "data1" : 123,
        "data2" : 456,
        "data3" : 789
      }
    }
  }
}
```

These are my rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    "folder": {
//    users cannot delete items in the node folder
      ".write": "newData.exists()",
//    item is a variable
      "$item": {
        "dataset1": {
//        dataset1 must have certain nodes and can't be deleted (set to null)
          ".validate": "data.hasChildren(['data1', 'data2', 'data3']) && newData.exists()",
          "data1": {".validate": "newData.isNumber()"},
          "data2": {".validate": "newData.isNumber()"},
          "data3": {".validate": "newData.isNumber()"},
//        using the variable $other means any node that isn't data1, data2, data3 is denied
          "$other": {".validate": false}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using the built in simulator I'm getting these results:

[image: The write is properly denied and doesn't let user set folder node to null]

This works when location is set to "/folder/item1" and "/folder/item1/dataset1"

[image: However when location is set to "/folder/item1/dataset1/data1" the write is allowed and the data is deleted.]

If I had deeper nodes in data1 they would all be deleted because the write was allowed.

Thanks for taking a read. Open to any answers, preferably I don't need to change the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear to me what you're asking. But there are a few problems with your rules, so I'll just point those out in hopes that they answer your question.

1. you grant write access on `/folder`, which you cannot take away at a lower level.
2. As long as any data is left under `/folder` any write is allowed. A thing to keep in mind is that `newData` is the data at the location as it will exist after the write operation; it is not just the new data that is written.
3. I have the impression that you're trying to prevent the deletion with `.validate` rules. Keep in mind that validation is not performed when deleting data, so you cannot use `.validate` rules to prevent deletion.

I suspect that #2 is causing your current problem.

Comment: Hi, I used your recommendations in point 2. I used "newData.hasChildren([example, example])" to ensure those children can't be deleted. Thanks for your help!